# Geometry: can a triangle be equilateral...

Tags: geometry

Problem from book: Can a triangle be equilateral, if distances from its vertices to two given perpendicular lines are expressed by whole number?

I do not understand this problem. Can someone perhaps restate it? Sorry for the bother but it seems interesting.

Edit:There is no figure in the problem. Image uploaded is just some random equilateral with random perpendicular line.

[image]

Comment: Can you rotate your image before uploading it please...

Comment: I think they are asking that if $\Delta ABC$ is equilateral, can all the segments $AA_i$, $BB_i$ and $CC_i$ have integer lengths?

Comment: Are you looking for a solution or just a restatement?

Comment: May be you can use coordinate geometry here. It becomes helpful in these cases rather than just abstract geometry.

Comment: Sorry, very slow upload speed.

Comment: @Dando18. Both will do. I like to do it first and if i am stuck I can refer to someon else's work?  Also, this chapter is on coordinates and I think that is what the author wants me te employ. I think I get it know. As what Ravi said, i think ALL is the word that I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks, everyone. I just finished solving it, but not too sure though. First i used coordinates and hypothesize that the 2 vertices lie on some integer whose distance is some real number R. Let A(a,b) and B(c,d), where a,b,c,d is some integer. Next, given AC=BC since equilateral, I solved for C(e,f) and got  e=((a+c)+(b-d)*Sqrt(3))/2 and f=((b+d)+(a-c)Sqrt(3))/2.

Answer (score 3):

Think of the two given perpendicular lines as the $x$ and $y$ axes (you can just rotate the given lines). Then, the problem is asking if you can have an equilateral triangle $ABC$ where $A = (a_1, a_2), B = (b_1, b_2), C = (c_1, c_2)$ are points in $\mathbb Z^2$ (that is, both coordinates are integers).

Comment: Ok, I'll do as you have suggested.

Comment: By the way, Pick's theorem might be useful here. Let me know if you want me to edit my answer with a solution.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, by translating by $(A_1,A_2)$ you get a simpler but equivalent problem. So now we can assume that $A$ is the intersection of the two line.
Let $l$ be the length of a side of the triangle, $B_1$, $B_2$, $C_1$,$C_2$ be the signed distance.
By bijection with the complex plane you get :

$$\exists \alpha \in \mathbb{R}/\begin{cases} A = 0 \\ B=le^{i\alpha} \\ C = le^{i(\alpha+\pi/3)} \end{cases}$$

And you know that :
$$\begin{cases} le^{i\alpha} =  B_1+i B_2\\ le^{i(\alpha+\pi/3)}  = C_1+ i C_2  \end{cases}$$

$$e^{i\pi/3}= \frac{B_1+i B_2}{ C_1+ i C_2} = \frac{(B_1+i B_2)(C_1- i C_2)}{ C_1^2+  C_2^2}$$

Now, taking the imaginary part :

$$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} =\frac{-B_1C_2+ B_2C_1}{ C_1^2+  C_2^2} $$
but $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} \in \mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$, $\frac{B_1C_2+ B_2C_1}{ C_1^2+  C_2^2} \in \mathbb{Q}$

Answer (score 0):

The problem is asking if there are equilateral triangles with their vertices in $\mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z}$.
The answer is negative: if $\ell$ is the side length of such a triangle, $\ell^2$ is a positive integer by the Pythagorean theorem. Since the area $\Delta$ is given by $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{4}\ell^2$, it follows that $4\Delta\in\sqrt{3}\mathbb{Z}^+$.
On the other hand, by the [shoelace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoelace_formula) we have $\Delta\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. 
$\sqrt{3}\mathbb{Z}^+$ and $\mathbb{Z}^+$ do not intersect since $\sqrt{3}\not\in\mathbb{Q}$, hence there aren't equilateral triangles made by lattice points.